# beautifulsoup finding text inside of attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

as the title says, i'm trying to figure out how to find text inside of attributes using BeautifulSoup, lets look at the example below, given the html:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input class="form-control" name="searchString" type="text" value="myString"/>
      <h2> your string is myString</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

im trying to find all the tags that has the text "myString" so i tried to do as follows:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "html.parser")
soup.find_all(text=re.compile("myString"))
```

but unfortunately it returns just one result

```
[' your string is myString']
```

ignoring the input that had the string i searched in its value attribute.
any suggestions?
thanks in advance

is there any generic way to get the tag if i don't know that my string appears in value attribute ? it could appear in any other attribute or even on an onClick event for example, how can i search for my string without knowing where it appears?
for this example i would have to write `soup.find_all(onclick=re.compile("myString"))`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For searching text inside value attribute, change `text` to `value`

```
results = soup.find_all(value=re.compile("myString"))
for r in results:
   # print(r)
   print('value: ' + r.get('value'))
```

note that `your string is myString` **is not text attribute**, it is `textContent` or just `text`

for searching if **contain any text or attributes** in tags, convert `bs4.element` to string or `outerHTML`

```
results= soup.find_all(True)
for r in results:
   if 'myString' in str(r):
       print(r)
       # <input class="form-control" name="searchString" type="text" value="myString"/>
       # <h2> your string is myString</h2>
```

And if in any **attributes only**

```
# <input class="myString bold" name="searchString" type="text" value="myString"/> 

results = soup.find_all(True)
for r in results:
    for attr in r.attrs:
        attrValue = r[attr]
        if 'class' == attr:
            attrValue = ' '.join(attrValue)
        if 'myString' in attrValue:
            print('%s : %s' % (attr, attrValue))
            # class : myString bold
            # value : myString
```

Comment: is there any generic way to get the tag if i don't know that my string appears in value attribute ? it could appear in any other attribute or even on an onClick event for example, how can i search for my string without knowing where it appears? thanks

Comment: you can convert tag to string with `str(tag)` see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

It finds the tag that contains the item.

Now you need to go through the results and pull the string you want from it.

That is the design of bs--allows you to find something entirely different inside a tag

```
import bs4
import re
html = """
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input class="form-control" name="searchString" type="text" value="myString"/>
      <h2> your string is myString</h2>
   </body>
</html>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
results = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("myString"))
print([re.findall("myString", result) for result in results])  # <-- here is where you iterate through the results

results.extend(soup.find_all('input', {"class":"form-control"}))  # Useful for divs, etc.
print(results[-1]['value'])
# This second set of results can be subscripted
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is that find_all returned only one result that represents the <h2> tag, so ur last line wont help since i need to get the input tag as well

Comment: Got it... apologies. These are two different asks and should be executed in two different lines of code for easy readability. Made appropriate edits to original response